# general css for all buttons, but change color for each based on id

Tags: html, css, background-color

I am not an html developer so I would like to ask how can you color buttons based on their id. I have general setup for all of it, but i would like to change color for each based on the id. Thank you.

```css
button {
  height:6vh;
  width:10vw;
  font-size:3vh;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  border:none;
}

button#0 {
  background-color:red;
}

button#1 {
  background-color:green;
}

button#2 {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<button  name="0" id="0" type="submit">0</button><button  name="1" id="1" type="submit">1</button><button  name="2" id="2" type="submit">2</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID can't start with number, so you can use class

```css
button {
  height: 6vh;
  width: 10vw;
  font-size: 3vh;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
}

.button0 {
  background-color: red;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.button2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button  name="0" id="0" class="button0" type="submit">0</button>
<button  name="1" id="0" class="button1" type="submit">1</button>
<button  name="0" id="2" class="button2" type="submit">2</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

the id in html is 0 not button0  so you should use a proper id name eg: #id0 in css

```
 #id0 {
   background-color:red;
```

}

or change the id in html

```
<button  name="button0" id="id0" type="submit">0</button>

 #button0 {
   background-color:red;
}
```

and the id must be unique

```
  <button  name="0" id="button0" type="submit">0</button>
  <button  name="0" id="botton1" type="submit">1</button>
  <button  name="0" id="button0" type="submit">2</button>
```

Comment: id can not start with number

Answer (score 1):

Id's cannot start with number. Read this article : https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/ and also id's should be unique, but that I think you just typed wrong in question.

As specified there you can use numbers for id's but it won't respond to classic selector `element#0` in exchange you can target `element[id='0']`.

Answer (score 1):

ID name cannot start with a number. For more info on naming ID and class see [this article.](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/naming_via_class_id_name.htm)

```css
button {
  height:6vh;
  width:10vw;
  font-size:3vh;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  border:none;
}

button#Btn0 {
  background-color:red;
}

button#Btn1 {
  background-color:green;
}

button#Btn2 {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<button  name="0" id="Btn0" type="submit">0</button><button  name="1" id="Btn1" type="submit">1</button><button  name="2" id="Btn2" type="submit">2</button>
```

Comment: For more info on naming ID and Class read this article https://www.kirupa.com/html5/naming_via_class_id_name.htm